# How to run Hobostove on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I just found this Terminal client for Campfire, but it doesn't say too much about how this (if possible) could be run on Ubuntu instead of OSX.

https://github.com/smartlogic/hobostove

How would I go about runnning this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Answer (score 0):

Installation should be the same as Mac if it's compatible with Ubuntu. Get `gem` package or use `rvm` (I recommend `rvm`)

[*->> Get RVM*](http://rvm.io/)

And the rest should be similar to the instructions given on github **if and only if** it's compatible with ubuntu. Sorry I could not comment this I don't have 50 reps. (this system of rep requirement for commenting should be fixed!)